# href pdf file url is not found when click on it

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, pdf, nuxt.js

I'm working on the vuejs application and, I'm receiving the pdf file from node backend which has the eg url `https:abc.com/api/filename.pdf`.

I'm using it link so

```
const myUrlVariable='https://someurl.com/dataCollection/imperial'
<a :href="myUrlVariable" target="_blank"></a>
```

The requirement of this is to when user click on link, file should open in the new tab.
But Right now when I click on the link its considering it as application route and show the message page not found, instead it show the pdf file.

I check this link in the postman and its returning the file as expected.

[image]

Comment: did you forgot to bind href `:href="myUrlVariable"`

Comment: Always lovely to debug that kind of thing with devtools.

Comment: Yes I did bind it

Comment: If I copy past that link in the browser tab so it still open the website with not found error

Comment: It could simply means that your file path is not correct.

Comment: So how its downloading from postman with the same link ? Its could be nginx problem ?

Answer (score 0):

`href` should not be a string, but a binding to a variable

Change this

```html
<a href="myUrlVariable" target="_blank"></a>
```

to this

```html
<a :href="myUrlVariable" target="_blank"></a>
```

Is the url correct?

`https:abc...` -> `https://abc...`

Comment: Yep, I already bind it, I've already verified it in devtool href has perfect link

Comment: Why not change your question to reflect that?